# Optional error while converting from Swift 2 to 3 in keyboardWillShow notification

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I am converting my app to Swift 3 at the moment and I have problems with this function I used to show the keyboard before.

**Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CGFloat'**

The error appears in the third line.

It's been a while since I've programmed the last time and so I am not sure how to solve this.

```
func keyboardWillShow(_ sender: Notification) {
        if let userInfo = sender.userInfo {
            if let keyboardHeight = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size.height {
                let duration = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).doubleValue
                let edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardHeight, 0)
                UIView.animate(withDuration: duration!, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView.contentInset = edgeInsets
                    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = edgeInsets
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
if let keyboardHeight = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size.height {
```

to

```
if let foo = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] {
    let keyboardHeight = (foo as as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size.height
```

--- UPDATE ---

or

```
if let keyboardHeight = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject?).cgRectValue.size.height {
```

`AnyObject?` works because `AnyObject` can contain `Optional` itself. So you have to casting to Optional explicitly. Either `AnyObject?` or `Optional<AnyObject>` will work.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those rare situations where I recommend force-unwrapping. You *know* the `userInfo` contains this information, and you are hosed if it doesn't. Moreover, there is no need to pass through AnyObject or to call `cgRectValue`; you can cast all the way down to a CGRect in a single move. So I would write:

```
    let keyboardHeight = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect).size.height
```

(Note that there is no `if`, because we are not doing a conditional binding; we simply cast, kaboom.)

[Note too that there is no need now to fetch the `duration` or to call `animate` or `layoutIfNeeded`; you can throw all of that away. We are *already* in an animation, and your changes to the `contentInset` and `scrollIndicatorInsets` will be animated in time to the keyboard.]